# Running R in Fi-Ware Cosmos

Tags: r, fiware, filab

I would like to use R for analysis within Cosmos (for those unfamiliar with cosmos: http://catalogue.fi-ware.org/enablers/bigdata-analysis-cosmos).

However, R is not installed, nor do I have the rights to install it.

Question to those working on Cosmos: is any chance you could install support for R?

Question to anyone else: is there any way to run R without being able to install or do anything that requires root privileges, ie. run as/within a java application or install locally for my user, or something else entirely. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the possibility to create a new VM in which you can install R (currently 3.0.2) and them connect this instance with the COSMOS or better to the HDFS system in order to work with the data that it contained inside it. Just move to the overview page of a deployed VM and click over "Edit" buttom close to "Installed Software" and select R to install it.

In fact, I prefer this option due to you separate the R process from the COSMOS machine and you have a dedicated infrastructure to produce whatever analysis that you want over the data.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!, Just to make sure I follow: 
I can make a connection from a new Fi-Lab VM with webHDFS or a HiveClient and then process the data in R in my new VM?

Comment: Yes, anyway if you require it, we can update the recipe of R with the last version.